# Sending Multiple flat files using Mutt Command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My requirement is to attach all the .csv files in a folder and send them in a single mail.

Here is what have tried.

```
mutt "$( printf -- '-a %q ' XXX*.csv )" -s "sending mail" DDD.RRR@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

But i am getting errors like Can't stat XXX.csv and : File name too long.

But when i tried a single file it's working perfectly with the below command.

```
mutt -a xxx-01-01_2016-01-02.csv -s "bfdsabj" ddd.rrr@visualiq.com < /dev/null
```

can any one help me on sending a mail by using mutt command.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
"$(printf -- '-a %q ' `ls *.csv`)"
```

or

```
"$(printf -- '-a %q ' `ls xxx*.csv`)"
```

Instead of

```
"$( printf -- '-a %q ' XXX*.csv )"
```

Here is updated command:

```
 mutt -a `ls xxx-*.csv` -- -s "sending mail" DDD.RRR@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

Comment: after changing with the new piece.  I'm getting the mail with 1file. but still getting above errors. and the strange thing is all the file names are adding to to list like thesexxxx_1.csv@dh536.dcbhs.com; xxxx_1.csv@dh536.dcbhs.com

Comment: mutt "$( printf -- '-a %q ' `ls xxx*.csv`)" -s "dbash" xab.dsad@gmail.com < /dev/null

Comment: mutt "$( printf -- '-a %q ' `ls xxx-*.csv` )" -- -s "sending mail" DDD.RRR@gmail.com.  no use getting    : unable to attach file.